# Erro no NPM ao criar um novo projeto angular

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, npm

[image: Tenho esse erro quando tendo criar um projeot angular]

Tenho esse erro quando tendo criar um projeot angular

Comment: Aqui tem a resolução para esse problema: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60185874/angular-9-ng-new-myapp-gives-error-the-schematic-workflow-failed

Answer (score -2):

Consegui resolver com essa sequência de comandos, executando um por vez:

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean --force
npm install -g @angular/cli@10.1.6
npm install yarn -g
ng config -g cli.packageManager yarn
```